# How to align contents in HTML

Tags: html, css

I designed a page in html as below. I want to align the numbers (121, 123) to the center and that arrows to be before the number.

But during my code design arrow makes those numbers to push towards right.

How Can I make those look properly ?

My Code is

```
<div class="thumbnail clearfix">
    <div class="caption">
        <h5>   
            <a>Unknown</a>
        </h5>
        <img src="images/image.png">
        <small><b>121</b></small>
        <br><small><b>0:0:4</b><br><b>10:20PM Mon, Nov.18</b>
        </small><br><a href="#" id="recentContactCall" phno="121" class="btn btn-primary">Poke</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Does the arrow have a functional use? Otherwise it would be better to make it a background image.

Comment: add right-margin: -20px; to the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base the arrow on the container of the numbers:

```html
<span class="value">123</span>
```

And then add in something like:

```css
.value {
    position: relative;
}

.value:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 25px; // arrow width
    height: 25px; // arrow height
    background: url('arrow.gif');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: -50px;
}
```

If you need support to extend back before pseudo elements were in the browsers, you'll need to actually nest the image:

```html
<span class="value">
    <img src="arrow.gif" />123
</span>
```

And then position it much like we did earlier:

```css
.value {
    position: relative;
}

.value img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: More or less what I was writing, but you beat me to it. :) `"If you need support to extend back before pseudo elements were in the browsers...."`. They are supported starting from IE8, so I hope not. ;)